# Parallel map in haskell

Tags: haskell, parallel-processing, multicore, combinators

Is there some substitute of `map` which evaluates the list in parallel? I don't need it to be lazy.

Something like: `pmap :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]` letting me `pmap expensive_function big_list` and have all my cores at 100%.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Yes, see the [parallel package](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/parallel/3.1.0.1/doc/html/Control-Parallel-Strategies.html):

```
ls `using` parList rdeepseq
```

will evaluate each element of the list in parallel via the `rdeepseq` strategy.  Note the use of `parListChunk` with a good chunk value might give better performance if your elements are too cheap to get a benefit evaluating each one in parallel (because it saves on sparking for each element).

EDIT: Based on your question I feel I should explain *why* this is an answer.  It's because Haskell is lazy!  Consider the statement

```
let bs = map expensiveFunction as
```

Nothing has been evaluated.  You've just created a thunk that maps `expensiveFunction`.  So how do we evaluate it in parallel?

```
let bs = map expensiveFunction as
    cs = bs `using` parList rdeepseq
```

Now don't use the `bs` list in your future computations, instead use the `cs` list.  IOW, you don't need a parallel map, you can use the regular (lazy) maps and a parallel evaulation strategy.

EDIT: And if you look around enough you'll see the [parMap](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/parallel/latest/doc/html/Control-Parallel-Strategies.html#v%3aparMap) function that does what I showed here but wrapped into one helper function.

In response to your comment, does the below code not work for you?  it works for me.

```
import Control.Parallel.Strategies

func as =
        let bs = map (+1) as
            cs = bs `using` parList rdeepseq
        in cs
```

Comment: I tried doing `pmap f x = (map f x) \`using\` parList rdeepseq`, but GHC is complaining that rdeepseq needs an argument.

Comment: @clark see the code I pasted - this should load into GHCi fine.  Does it work for you?  The expression `parMap rdeepseq f as` should do the same thing.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. "No instance for (Control.DeepSeq.NFData b) arising from a use of `rdeepseq'"

Comment: @clark you must be using it in a particular context or with an explicit type signature.  Be sure the elements of your list have an `NFData` instance - that is required for use of `rdeepseq`.  If that is too onerous then use `rseq` instead, which evalutes to whnf.

Comment: Okay. I did it with parMap, but I'm still only using one core here =/

Comment: @clark Did you compile with threaded (`ghc -O2 -threaded blah.hs --make`)  and use the right RTS options (`./blah +RTS -Nx`) where `x` is the number of cores you want to use, such as `2`?  Note on GHC 7 you should just be able to type `ghc -O2 -threaded -with-rtsopts=-N blah.hs` and run `./blah`.

Comment: @TomMD: Yes I did. Does it matter than I'm on Windows?

Comment: @clark No, Windows should work fine.  Could you edit your question with the exact code you compiled, the compilation line (also using `-fforce-recomp`, just to be sure) and how you executed it?  Also, find me on #haskell in IRC if you want to work this out real-time.

Comment: Does this also work when working with datastructures you defined yourself in the list you map over? I tried this approach but I get `No instance for (NFData myDataType)` error

Comment: It works if the type has an instance for NFData, as you observed you need.

Answer (score 22):

Besides using explicit strategies yourself as Tom has described, the [parallel](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/parallel) package [also exports `parMap`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/parallel/3.1.0.1/doc/html/Control-Parallel-Strategies.html#v:parMap):

```
 parMap :: Strategy b -> (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
```

where the strategy argument is something like `rdeepseq`.

And there's also `parMap` in the par-monad package (you step out of pure Haskell, and into a parallel monad):

```
 parMap :: NFData b => (a -> b) -> [a] -> Par [b]
```

The par-monad package is [documented here](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/monad-par/0.1.0.1/doc/html/Control-Monad-Par.html#v:parMap).

Comment: There is a small caveat here.  parMap is using mapM, which is strict.  This means that the list spine is fully evaluated before computation starts - if the list is long, e.g. you are parMap'ping over records read from a (huge) file, this is probably not what you want.  Perhaps this would work better with a lazy parMap, or by distributing elements round-robin.