# Haskell -- parallel map that makes less sparks

Tags: performance, haskell, parallel-processing, multicore

I want to write a parallel map function in Haskell that's as efficient as possible. My initial attempt, which seems to be currently best, is to simply write,

```
pmap :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
pmap f = runEval . parList rseq . map f
```

I'm not seeing perfect CPU division, however. If this is possibly related to the number of sparks, could I write a pmap that divides the list into *# of cpus* segments, so there are minimal sparks created? I tried the following, but the peformance (and number of sparks) is much worse,

```
pmap :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
pmap f xs = concat $ runEval $ parList rseq $ map (map f) (chunk xs) where
    -- the (len / 4) argument represents the size of the sublists
    chunk xs = chunk' ((length xs) `div` 4) xs
    chunk' n xs | length xs <= n = [xs]
                | otherwise = take n xs : chunk (drop n xs)
```

The worse performance may be correlated with the higher memory use. The original pmap does scale somewhat on 24-core systems, so it's not that I don't have enough data.
(The number of CPU's on my desktop is 4, so I just hardcoded that).

#### Edit 1

Some performance data using `+RTS -H512m -N -sstderr -RTS` is here:

- [my 4-core desktop](http://pastebin.com/8fpcxSG6)
- [24-core server](http://pastebin.com/EZxtcV7u)

Comment: Tuning `parMap` to spark once for each core isn't a sure way to go - each element might take a different amount of work to compute.  For example, in the trivial `fib` implementation, the work increases significantly for each successive element, so placing the last `n` elements in the same spark will result in very little parallelism.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [parallel](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/parallel) package defines a number of parallel map *strategies* for you:

```
parMap :: Strategy b -> (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
```

A combination of parList and map, and specific support for chunking the list:

```
parListChunk :: Int -> Strategy a -> Strategy [a]
```

Divides a list into chunks, and applies the strategy `evalList strat` to each chunk in parallel.

You should be able to use a combination of these to get any sparking behavior you desire. Or, for even more control, [the `Par` monad](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/monad-par) package, for controlling the amount of threads created (purely).

---

*References:* The [haddock docs for the parallel package](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/parallel/3.1.0.1/doc/html/Control-Parallel-Strategies.html)

Comment: Great, that gives some control over the number of sparks. Sorry I missed it on hackage ... at least it's on stackoverflow now. Unfortunately, performance isn't much better, but likely my fault.Oddly, `-g1` for parallel garbage collection brings the garbage collection stat way down, but runtime doesn't change...

Comment: @gatoatigrado: try using with `-qa` and `-qg`.  These two options sometimes help gc performance of parallel programs.  Sometimes they're worse though, so be sure to test them.

Comment: in case anyone visits this question, the answer at this sister question might be useful (in particular, the rdeepseq), http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5606165/parallel-map-in-haskell